# Check for deleted data using Sails and Waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, soft-delete

I am new to `SailsJS` and using it for an application and facing some issues with queries while deleting a `Project` Model
Project Model:

```
name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      },
deletedAt: {
             type: 'datetime'
           },  
deletedBy: {
        model: 'User',
    }
```

User Model:

```
name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      },
email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      }
```

On creating a project, Sails automatically fills in data for createdAt and updatedAt and I am filling in data for Project `Name`
On deleting a project, I need to do a soft-delete, where In I will be setting `deletedAt` value and `deletedBy` values.
On getting list of all projects, It should not get deleted projects.
One way I thought of was to get all projects using query:

```
Project.find(function (err, projList) {
..
}
```

and then for each project do a check as follows:

```
if (project.hasOwnProperty('deletedBy') && project.deletedBy != null) {
   //Dont include this in list 
  }
```

Is there any way, Instead of I manually checking for deleted projects, Can it be done using queries? i.e. Omitting all deleted projects.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is your questions complete? You list the user model here, but your question does not ask anything about the user model.

Answer (score 1):

```
Project
    .find()
    .where({deletedAt : null})
    .exec(function(err, projectList){
..
});
```

Depending on your model / db you may have to setup deletedAt with defaultsTo: null

```
name: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
},
deletedAt: {
    type: 'datetime',
    defaultsTo: null,
},  
deletedBy: {
    model: 'User',
}
```